# Scala defining a function and call it on left side of parameter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
val deck = 1 to 52 toList

// shuffles the deck, and prints it out nicely
deck sortWith ((_, _) => Random.nextBoolean) foreach (x => print(x + " "))
```

Since I will be shuffling and printing the deck over and over, I am trying to do the following

```
val deck = 1 to 52 toList
def shuffle : (List[Int] => List[Int]) = {_ sortWith ((_, _) => Random.nextBoolean)}
def printDeck : (List[Int] => Unit) = {_ foreach(x => print(x + " "))}

deck shuffle printDeck // this doesnt work

// I can only do 
printDeck(shuffle(deck)) // this works
```

Calling the function on left side of parameter is a lot more elegant when you don't have to use parenthesis.

Comment: Just for fun, you can also `(shuffle andThen printDeck)(deck)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get `object function` syntax, you would have to have the function as a method on the class.

You could accomplish this with an implicit definition:

```
implicit def enhanceDeck(deck: List[Int]) = new {
  def shuffle = 
    deck sortWith ((_, _) => Random.nextBoolean)

  def printDeck = 
    deck.foreach(x => print(x + " "))
}
```

Now you can do:

```
val deck = 1 to 52 toList
deck shuffle 
deck printDeck
```

But you *can't* do `deck shuffle printDeck` because Scala thinks that you are doing `deck.shuffle(printDeck)`.  Instead, use one of:

```
deck.shuffle.printDeck
deck.shuffle printDeck
```

**EDIT**: Your first snippet is actually `object function arg function arg`.  Both `sortWith` and `foreach` take one argument.

Defining a type for `Deck` would probably be a good approach for cleanliness, but would still not allow you to use the syntax you want because you would just have something like `Deck(deck) shuffle printDeck` which Scala would assume to be `Deck(deck).shuffle(printDeck)`.

It would look like this:

```
case class Deck(deck: List[Int]) {
  def shuffle = 
    deck sortWith ((_, _) => Random.nextBoolean)

  def printDeck = 
    deck.foreach(x => print(x + " "))
}

Deck(deck).shuffle printDeck
```

Comment: My first code snippet is `object function function` form, if I define an OO type for deck, like Vlad suggested, would `object function function` form be possible?

Comment: @qin, Edited for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to have

```
deck <?> shuffle <?> printDeck
```

instead of

```
printDeck(shuffle(deck))
```

you should consider using the `|>` operator (defined in [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/), or just create your own) because that is what it is good for

```
deck |> shuffle |> printDeck
```

While there may be valid points against using the *forward pipe* in Scala in general, if you really just want to reverse the order, things will be a lot clearer with this generic operator than creating specific pimps to `List[Int]`.

Definition (only for reference; please do not use this as an implementation):

```
implicit def toForwardPipe[T](x : T) = new {
  def |> [U](f : T => U) = f(x)
}
```

Comment: Just don't do it this way. There are serious performance issues with enriching like that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral [citation needed]. Shouldn't the compiler be smart enough to optimize it away?

Comment: @DanBurton _Could_ the compiler be smart enough to optimize it away? Yes. _Is it?_ No. The general case of existential types cannot be optimized while preserving identity -- it needs to go through reflection. No effort is spent by the compiler to optimize existential types (well, I lie -- it actually has a caching scheme that helps some). With Scala 2.10, I think this can be completely optimized away, but it does require you to use the proper incantations.